# Date Time Conversion

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I want to convert `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`.
My application is asp.NET with VB.
I tried following code

```
DateTime.Parse(oldDate.ToString("dd\mm\yyyy"))
```

But got the error:

```
"The string was not recognized as a valid dateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 2"
```

Can any one give the appropriate code?

Comment: This isn't your solution, but just for reference: be careful - lowercase m's are minutes; uppercase M's are months.

Answer (score 4):

In VB:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = _
    DateTime.ParseExact(oldDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

' and then if you want to format it in dd/MM/yyyy format
Dim s As String = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

In C#:

```
DateTime dt =
    DateTime.ParseExact(oldDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// and then if you want to format it in dd/MM/yyyy format
string s = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the \ characters.

Answer (score 0):

if oldDate is a DateTime then all you need to do is

```
    Dim oldDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    Dim odS As String 'old date as string
    odS = oldDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy").Insert(4, "\").Insert(2, "\")
```

changing the string format does not change the DateTime.  DateTime's are numbers, not strings.